# PowerShell Renaming File

Tags: powershell

I have a script I found and then modified a bit for renaming **Movie** files with names such as the following:

**From**

```
"The.Titan.2018.1080p.WEBRip.x264-[YTS.AM].mp4"
```

**To**

```
"The Titan 2018.mp4"
```

**Code I use and modified for my needs**

```
Set-Location "X:\AUTOMATED_FILM_&_TV_SHOWS\2_SEPERATING_FOLDER\MOVIES"
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object{$_.BaseName -Match '(.*?\.(19|20)\d{2})\..*'} | Rename-Item -NewName {($_.BaseName -replace '(.*?\.(19|20)\d{2})\..*','$1')+$_.Extension}
dir -Filter *.mp4 | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName.replace("."," ") + $_.Extension }
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to make modifications to this code to rename my **TV Show** files with names such as the following:

**From**

```
"Quantico.S03E04.720p.HDTV.x264-KILLERS.mp4"
```

I would like it to alter the file name

**To**

```
"Quantico S03E04.mp4
```

Comment: could you please point me into the right direction where i can discuss this then.. as i assumed this is just like any forum

Comment: i never said you did answer it correctly but thanks for the help anyway

Comment: What you need is a tutorial on .net regex. Read up on it. You can also find online regex testers. So you can practice.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [ForEach](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach.html) loop statement with PowerShell and utilize the [Split()](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html) method accordingly iterating the files with the [Get-ChildItem](https://ss64.com/ps/get-childitem.html) command and then rename the files accordingly assuming you always need the files in that folder to be renamed with the parts before the first dot and before the second dot plus the original extension.

### Example Script

```
$Folder = "X:\AUTOMATED_FILM_&_TV_SHOWS\2_SEPERATING_FOLDER\MOVIES"
$Files = Get-ChildItem $Folder -filter "*.mp4" 

Foreach ($file in $Files){
    $s = [String]$file
    $ext = $file.Extension
    $name = ($s.Split(".")[0] + " " + $s.Split(".")[1] + $ext) 
    Rename-Item -Path $file -NewName $name
}
```

---

### Further Resources

- [ForEach](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach.html)
- [Get-ChildItem](https://ss64.com/ps/get-childitem.html)
- [Split()](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html)

Answer (score 2):

Hi all thanks for the help,

Pimp Juice thanks for altering the question more appropriately..
I've had a dig round on the internet into the regex and made some trial and error..

Managed to generate a code which works to but by all means its got improvement to make it more efficient but for the file names i am receiving don't vary much at all so

The Code that seems to work is below

```
Set-Location "C:\Users\BRACEGIRDLE\Favorites\Desktop\RENAME"
Dir -Filter *.mkv | Get-ChildItem | Where-Object{$_.BaseName -Match "(.*?\.[A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z][0-9][0-9])\..*"} | Rename-Item -NewName {($_.BaseName -replace "(.*?\.[A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z][0-9][0-9])\..*",'$1')+$_.Extension}
Dir -Filter *.mkv | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName.replace("."," ") + $_.Extension }

Dir -Filter *.mp4 | Get-ChildItem | Where-Object{$_.BaseName -Match "(.*?\.(19|20)\d{2})\..*"} | Rename-Item -NewName {($_.BaseName -replace "(.*?\.(19|20)\d{2})\..*",'$1')+$_.Extension}
Dir -Filter *.mp4 | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName.replace("."," ") + $_.Extension }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this question bubbled up to the Home page, an alternate **PowerShell** solution ( still using `.Split()`, I think it makes for faster comprehension when scanning code ):

```
$Folder = 'X:\AUTOMATED_FILM_&_TV_SHOWS\2_SEPERATING_FOLDER\MOVIES'

Get-ChildItem $Folder *.mp4 | Rename-Item -NewName {
    $Parts = $_.Name.Split('.')
    '{0} {1}.{2}' -f $Parts[0], $Parts[1], $Parts[-1]
}
```